# How to add optional parameters in REST API?

Tags: python, json, rest, python-requests

I am using the following REST API: https://rest.ensembl.org/documentation/info/vep_hgvs_get

An example of the code for this is as follows:

```
server = "https://rest.ensembl.org"
ext = "/vep/human/hgvs/ENSP00000401091.1:p.Tyr124Cys?"
r = requests.get(server+ext, headers={ "Content-Type" : "application/json"})
```

On the documentation page, it says it has an optional parameter as follows:

| Name | Description | Example Values |
| --- | --- | --- |
| dbNSFP | Include fields from dbNSFP, a database of pathogenicity predictions for missense variants. Multiple fields should be separated by commas. See dbNSFP README for field list. (plugin details) | LRT_pred,MutationTaster_pred |

Does anyone know how I would incorporate the dbNSFP value into this REST API query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can by using `params`

e.g.

```
server = "https://rest.ensembl.org"
ext = "/vep/human/hgvs/ENSP00000401091.1:p.Tyr124Cys?"
params = {"dbNSFP": "LRT_pred"}
r = requests.get(server+ext, params=params, headers={ "Content-Type" : "application/json"})
```